# Handle async actions that do not store result in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I stumbled upon a requirement on a section of a vanilla JS webapp that requires a single JSON "definitions" object to render. Definitions are **loaded** via an `HTTP` request **at the very beginning**, read, parsed **and handed down to another layer of the app**. The object itself never changes throughout its life cycle.

I'm now trying to model this scenario in [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/), using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) + [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#redux-thunk). I created a thunk/async action the fetches the JSON object, extracts what it needs and ends up updating the state with that -
 but it does *not store the object itself* in the state. This seems like the right, logical approach since, as mentioned, the definitions are never modified in any way. I'd argue it's simply **not state**, in a strict sense.

However, by taking that decision I ended up struggling while implementing the actual `React.Component`. Almost every single [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html#containersasyncappjs) I've seen out there in the wild for async cases like this one:

- Defines a thunk action that fires some API call.
- Stores whatever they got back (or after some alterations) in a state property.
- Maps that property to `this.props` in the Component with `mapStateToProps` and `connect`.

In my case, **I don't really have a state property to bind to**. So I ended up returning the definitions object in my async action and using the component's local state to get what I needed.

```
class ContainerComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { definitions: {} };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchDefinitions())
      .then((definitions) => this.setState({ definitions }));
  }

  render() {
    return (<PresentationalComponent definitions={this.state.definitions} />);
  }
}

export default connect()(ContainerComponent);
```

Not saying that `this.setState` should [be avoided](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate), but this looks an awful lot like **what I had before even introducing Redux**: an API call returning a promise - only with a lot more meddling indirections.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    fetch(`${API_URL}/definitions`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((definitions) => this.setState({ definitions }));
  }
```

So, how should I go about this? Is there any particular thing I am missing here? Any pattern I should be following? Perhaps, avoiding Redux entirely for this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that having a component state isn't necessarily a bad thing, but I believe you are confused on where to store that data once the API call is made.

You mention that it is not necessarily state, but I would argue otherwise. Prior to making the API call, your application does not have that data. You may have certain UX/UI indications at the start up of your application that, for example could indicate on if the data is being fetched: `definitions.all.isFetching`.

In your `componentDidMount`, dispatching the action to fetch the data is correct. Once the action is fired, and the success response is received, your reducer should save the definitions to your redux store like

```
import { assign, get } from 'lodash';

const all = (
  state = { isFetching: false, data: [] },
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LIST_DEFINITIONS:
      return assign({}, state, { isFetching: true });
    case types.LIST_DEFINITIONS_SUCCESS:
      return assign({}, state, get(action, 'result.data'), { isFetching: false });
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Then in your component, you would `connect` your redux store

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    definitions: state.definitions.all.data
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { listDefinitions })(ContainerComponent);
```

Also note I moved the action out in my example and am placing it into the connect with `mapDispatchToProps` shorthand.

Comment: Ok. Your explanation makes sense to me - to some extent. Your argument for including a huge (did not mention that, but it's rather large in my case), pretty much useless object after its first (and only) use in the shared state is showing some kind of a spinner? Doesn't seem like a good trade-off. Also, I could handle that with local state as well. Isn't this more like a way of trying to forcely fit the solution into the framework?

Comment: Redux is simply a state management tool. You can use if it you like, but you don't have to. Everything you do in the development of your app is up to you, and there are many means to similar ends.

Whenever I build an app, I account for when a request to an API fails. I can't guarantee that my `definitions` will always return to me, and I would like to have UX/UI developed to reflect when the response is being fetched or is received by my application. If you have the functionality and organizational structure that you need without redux, feel free to remove it- it is your app after all.

Comment: Fair enough. My question was more in the lines of: "Is there any other approach to this than what I did?". You certainly gave one. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!